# What is the meaning of "For Good"?

Tags: idioms

What's the meaning of "for good"?

For instance, one says "Are you leaving?"
The other replies "Yes, for good."

Comment: You might find this answer useful at EL&U. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40771/why-does-for-good-mean-forever

Answer (score 9):

> Yes, for good.

*for good* means you are leaving for the last time. You will NEVER come back.

Check this definition: [***for good***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+good)